# How to increase and decrease a series of number in loop

Tags: c++, loops

I tried to get a output like this:

```
               1
           2   4   2
        3  5   7   5   3
    4   6  8   10  8   6   4
5   7   9  11  13  11  9   7   5
```

and I wrote this code:

```
int input_n = 0;
int x;
int rowNumber = 1;

std::cin >> input_n;

int result = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= input_n; i++)
{
    std::cout << std::setw(10 - i);
    rowNumber = i;
    int addCounter = rowNumber - 1;

    if (rowNumber == 1)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(11) << rowNumber;
    }
    else 
    {
        for (x = 1; x <= rowNumber + 1; x++)
        {
            std::cout << rowNumber << std::setw(3);
            // What Should do here?
        }

    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

Finally I got this output:

```
              1
           2  2  2
         3  3   3   3
       4   4   4   4   4
     5   5   5   5   5   5
```

I'm just confused, how I just can get like above output? I tried many loop whiles and for. but I didn't get the right output.

Comment: Where's your [mcve]? Don't forget to show your debugging efforts, and what's unclear from your observations.

Comment: Obviously `std::setw(10 - i);` cannot work for 2 spaces as in the example

Comment: And this only displays the same number all the time: `std::cout << rowNumber << std::setw(3);`

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Thats my problem. I need to increase by 2 and decrease by 2. like first example

Comment: Well, obviously you are missing a value here, like a multiplier?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I think I need another loop for increase and decrease the value. right at my comment in code

Comment: You don't need another loop, you just need to use something like `rowNumber * std::min(x, rowNumber-x)`.

Comment: "How to increase and decrease a series of number in loop" - Well, `operator+` and `operator-` of course; 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example by your code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::ostream;
using std::ostringstream;
using std::right;
using std::setw;
using std::string;

void tree(ostream&, int n);

void tree(ostream& o, int n)
{
    auto indent = [](auto amount) { return string(static_cast<string::size_type>(amount), ' '); };
    auto format = [](auto value) { ostringstream s; s << right << setw(3) << value; return s.str(); };

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        o << indent((n - i) * 3);

        for (int x = 1; x < i * 2; ++x)
        {
            o << format(i + (x - 1) * 2 + (x > i ? x - i : 0) * -4);
        }

        o << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    int input_n = 0;

    if (cin >> input_n)
    {
        tree(cout, input_n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Take a look to this

[Arithmetic progression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) ,should clarify the process of increasing and decreasing with reason 2 the numbers.
The number of digit in a line is `rownumber + rownumber - 1`  or `2*rownumber -1` , then the numbers increase by two for `(rownumber*2-)/2` and then start decreasing by two.

Comment: @AliSepehri-Amin Sorry, I am on the mobile, can't write